# Project Jigsaw / Java Platform Module System

Tags: java, plugins, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I am currently evaluating possibilities to develop a plugin concept for a desktop application.
When researching I found out about OSGI and the Java Platform Module System (or Project Jigsaw).
I am a little bit confused about the Specifications of the Java Platform Module System.

- Will the Java Platform module System allow Modules to be added like Plugins? 
  Will it possible to declare optional Modules and access their services?
- Will it be possible for Modules to have their own classpath and be separated from the rest of the application?
- Will it be possible for third party programmers to implement plugins that seamlessly integrate into an existing application?

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me understand the specification.

Comment: FYI, the spec for the Module System is [JSR 376](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=376). Also, some good books have now been published on the topic.

Comment: Just do not mix OSGI with Jigsaw as it won't work as expected. Good read about it: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/musings-about-jigsaw-the-java-9-module-system

Comment: This is another good read about that topic on developer.jboss.org: [Concerns Regarding Jigsaw(JSR-376, Java Platform Module System)](https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/scott.stark/2017/04/14/critical-deficiencies-in-jigsawjsr-376-java-platform-module-system-ec-member-concerns)